# Starting a conversation with a chat bot hosted on Microsoft Azure through HTTP request in Python

Tags: python, azure, http

A Microsoft [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-1-1-start-conversation) shows that in order to set up a conversation with a bot I should issue the following HTTP request:

```
POST https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations
Authorization: Bearer SECRET_OR_TOKEN
```

My question is if I can achieve this with the following Python code:

```
import requests
r = requests.post('https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations', 
                params = {'Authorization':'Bearer ftmhNAqZ2tw.cwA.qIA.Xz2ZWfYJzxd8vJjcK9VmINWNLxlvKiM5jC8F_cbaf0s'})
```

If I print the response with `print(r.content)` it says:

> {   "error": {
>       "code": "BadArgument",
>       "message": "Missing token or secret"   } }

Comment: You're supposed to be sending a *header*, not a query parameter. Also you now need to revoke that token and get a new one.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please provide a code example or a link to where it's explained?

Comment: Where *what* is explained? If you want to know how to add headers using `requests`, **read the docs**.

Comment: The API doesn't state that it should be sent as a header, but it is very standard for `Authorization` to be a header (and in this case - it is the case). *[Might also be worth pointing out that sharing your API keys in stackoverflow questions isn't always wise]*

Comment: It doesn't state that it should be a query param either; in that case they'd show it in the URL, surely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP requests have three areas where content can be sent:

- URL parameters
- Body
- Headers

To set these in python's `requests` package the following can be used (POST method assumed, but all are the same):

**URL Parameters**:

```
requests.post('https://myurl.com', params = {'MyParam':'MyValue'})
# equivilient to http://myurl.com?MyParam=MyValue
```

**Body**:

```
requests.post('https://myurl.com', data={"key":"value"})
# or if sending json data
requests.post('https://myurl.com', data=json.dumps(myData))
```

**Headers**:

```
requests.post('https://myurl.com', headers={"headername":"value"})
```

---

In your specific case, while the API is not well documented - we can assume they expect the "Authorization" data to be sent in a header, as this is standard. In this case, you need to assign headers as follows:

```
requests.post('https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations', headers={'Authorization':'Bearer ftmhNAqZ2tw.cwA.qIA.Xz2ZWfYJzxd8vJjcK9VmINWNLxlvKiM5jC8F_cbaf0s'})
```

Answer (score 0):

The bearer token needs to be sent as a header, not as a payload or query parameter.

You need to use the `headers` argument:

```
auth = {'Authorization': 'Bearer xxxYourBearerTokenHerexxx'}
r = requests.post('https://directline.botframework.com/api/conversations', headers=auth)

print(r) # <Response [200]>
```